# C# ResXResourceSet not being resolved following official examples

Tags: c#, .net

According to [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2), there is supposed to be `ResXResourceSet` class in `System.Resources` namespace.

> // Get resources from .resx file.
>   using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile)) 
>   { ...

However, it cannot be resolved in my .NET 4.5 console application:

```
using (var resx = new System.Resources.ResXResourceSet(path))
...
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ResXResourceSet' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Resources' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something? The examples tutorial does not mention any required assemblies and the `System.Resources` namespace itself can be found and contains a class with similar name - `ResourceSet` which however, appears to be working with binary files only.

Comment: Thanks it was the problem, consider posting it as an answer. The other official [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) do not include `Windows.Forms` as well as it is not mentioned anywhere in the document, so that is probably error in documentation. So this will be probably helpful for future reference for other people following that tutorial as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourceset(v=vs.110).aspx) for this class states that required assembly is System.Windows.Forms. This info is stated for every .NET class, on corresponding page

The link you provided is just an overall description of how things work with several mentioned classes. But in general case each class in that description may be in different namespace or different assembly, so the information about that is always written for each class separately, on the main page of the class.